# ASP.NET Core integration tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, integration-testing

I'm following the pattern from this MS doc :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase("MyDb");
                options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
            });

            serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopedProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var myDb = scopedProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
                var logger = scopedProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>>>();

                myDb.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
        });

        builder.UseContentRoot(".");
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
    }
}
```

but on this line

```
var myDb = scopedProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
```

I'm receiving error

> Entity Framework services have not been added to the internal service
>   provider. Either remove the call to UseInternalServiceProvider so that
>   EF will manage its own internal services, or use the method from your
>   database provider to add the required services to the service provider
>   (e.g. AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer).

This makes no sense to be because I believe I am adding EF services to the internal service provider on this line :

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are using:

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection() .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase() .BuildServiceProvider();
```

The above will get overridden by the following line as `AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()` is not part of the services parameter.

```
serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Replace the above with:

```
//Build the service provider.
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Then create the scope using `sp`. I hope that helps

Comment: I was assuming ( wrongly ) that `options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);` would set an internal reference to the first `ServiceProvider` instance